# Is "All were happy" correct?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to write "All were happy", for example in the end of a story?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you doubt it? What do you think?

Comment: For me it sounds better to say "Everyone was happy", I don't know why...

Comment: **Everyone** or **everybody** is singular and requires a singular verb such as **was**. **All**, referring to people or items, is plural and takes **were**. (Although we say **all was well**, using the singular, where **all** means the situation.) So you can choose. Both are fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it is correct, however, at the end of a story it's more common to see something like:

> They all ended up happy and had many children.

Comment: While the given example is grammatical, I have never seen it in any story.